# Google sheets displays formula below cell where it's written

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to figure this out for days now.

I'm trying to create a file to better track my stocks.  The problem I'm having is that when I'm trying to pull a historical price, it displays the date and price on the row below[2] (it's written in D4, price shows in E5).  Ideally it would just produce the answer in the cell I write the formula in.  How do I get the results of the formula to display on the same row as the formula?  I will be adding other stocks below this one and I don't want to assign 2 rows to 1 stock.

*Here is a screenshot:*

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the price use index. Query is not needed:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(A4,"price",workday(today()-30,2,0)),2,2)
```